# ¿Como encontrar un elemento en una lista de objeto con linq en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, objeto

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
                List<ConsumosInsumosDetalleModels> lista_mae = new List<ConsumosInsumosDetalleModels>();
                string empresa = Session["ss_Empresa"].ToString();
                DataTable dt_lv = new DataTable();
                String sql = "";
                sql += " SELECT";
                sql += " libro.comprobante,";
                sql += " librod.codigo,";
                sql += " librod.detalle,";
                sql += " from libro";
                sql += " left join librod on librod.registro=libro.registro";
                sql += " where libro.empresa=@empresa and libro.tipomov='CI' and libro.centro>0 AND libro.anulado=0 ";
                

                conexion.conectar();
                MySqlDataAdapter datosM = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.con);
                datosM.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empresa", empresa);
                datosM.Fill(dt_lv);
                conexion.cerrar();
                foreach (DataRow datos_tabla in dt_lv.Rows)
                {
                    lista_mae.Add(new ConsumosInsumosDetalleModels
                    {
                        numero = datos_tabla["comprobante"].ToString(),
                        codigo = datos_tabla["codigo"].ToString(),
                        detalle = datos_tabla["detalle"].ToString()
                       
                    });
                }
                IEnumerable<ConsumosInsumosDetalleModels> list = lista_mae.AsQueryable();

                if (searchValue != "")
                {
                    list = list.Where(d => d.detalle.Contains(searchValue));
                }
                                   

                recordsTotal = list.Count();
                lista_mae = list.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

El problema ocurre que cuando quiero buscar una palabra en el campo detalle que viene de la variable searchValue, por ejemplo el campo d.detalle tiene una columna con el nombre lamina y cuando empiezo a colocar la palabra "la", no encuentra nada:

```
      if (searchValue != "")//el searchValue tiene la palabra "la"
                {
                    list = list.Where(d => d.detalle.Contains(searchValue));
                }
```

Pero cuando llego en el punto de interrupción, al siguiente codigo:

```
     recordsTotal = list.Count();
```

Tae 0 elementos, me gustaría saber como podría resolver esto, ya que no encuentra el elemento por el nombre del campo detalle.

Espero que se entienda, desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Estás seguro que `lista_mae` trae datos? En caso de ser afirmativo, trae algun detalle que contenga el `searchValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso sucede porque en tu consulta en sql es especifica, deberias usar [`LIKE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  si buscas un texto en especifico

`sql += " where libro.empresa LIKE '%' + @empresa + '%' and libro.tipomov='CI' and libro.centro>0 AND libro.anulado=0 ";`

Comment: Entiendo que puede utilizarse LIKE en la consulta SQL, pero la pregunta de OP es cómo utilizar el método `Contains()` para filtrar sobre la propiedad `detalle`. Aquí estás filtrando por Empresa. No es lo que OP pide

Comment: @Arriel Cuanto usa `contains` esta haciendo una busqueda en sql, porque no esta usando `identity`, porque hace la consulta y lo agrega a un list `lista_mae.Add` y a ese list le hace el `where` para consultar el `searchvalue`